# I need bare-metal hypervisors for home use

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

So let me try to explain what i want. I search a lot on the internet but i did not find. So i want an hyper-visor bare-metal. All i want is something like `Vmware` but to be installed on bare-metal, not on some platform host.

I find Xenserver but you cannot access the interface of virtual machines from the same machine. (You should use `Xencenter` to access it).

I do not have two machines,and i want to know if somebody have an idea about some technology.

Comment: Did you look at [proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seems like you do not have any restrictions about technologies and hypervisors providers , I can advise you then to use `Hyper-v` of `Microsoft` but to use it as a bare-metal hypervisor you should install `Windows Server` (or the `System Center` Manager) before, then activate the `Hyper-v` role on it and Reboot.. here is a tuto , check it maybe that will help you : http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/install-hyper-v-bare-metal/